# Beginner at Python (Timer help)

Tags: python, timer, computer-science

I am making a questionnaire using python and want to have a visible timer on the questionnaire. The code I used for the timer is below but when it is counting down, it creates a new line and would not let the rest of my questionnaire run. Please help!

```
import os
import time
s=59
m=5
while s<=59:
    os.system('cls')
    print ( m, "Minutes", s, "Seconds")
    time.sleep(1)
    s-=1
    if s==0:
        m-=1
        s=59
```

Comment: Apparently you run both your "timer" and your questionnaire on the same thread. You might want to look into multithreading or multiprocessing.

Comment: I wouldn't reset the s=59 in the while loop, try that outside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are two problems:

1. Your timer loop blocks the rest of your application
2. Printing the current time gives a newline and makes the screen scroll

To solve 1 use threads or processes. Timer and questionaire are in a different thread.

To solve 2 you could use escape sequences to control the screen. But since your questionaire will have to scroll without scrolling your timer, this really begs for a GUI. Tcl/Tk is the GUI library that comes with Python. It will be the easiest to use that, I expect.